# Get xml from website by webrequest then deserialize it and show in console

Tags: c#, webrequest, xml-deserialization

Hello i learning about this stuff an i need to send request to site get xml in response than deserialize it and see anything what was inside... i created request deserialize method and stream method and Xml Schema but now i dont know what next and it doest working so if anybody know about some nice tutorial pls give me link.

```
public static class LoadXml
{
    public static root material;



    public static void LoadXML()
    {
        var serviceUrl = "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/27&output=xml";
        string serviceName = "Deezer";

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        WebResponse response = null;

        request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = " text/xml";



        material = Deserialize<root>(GetResponseStream(request, response, serviceName));

        Console.WriteLine(material.ToString());
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        return result;
    }

    public static MemoryStream GetResponseStream(HttpWebRequest request, WebResponse response, string debugServiceName)
    {

        response = request.GetResponse();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place (or load) the results into an [XDocument][1] and work with it from there by manipulating and extracting data from the document.

Using the url as a starting point this is a snippet (easier way to load; try it) where we load it and then look at a target child node if the structure returned was (\root\name):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/27&output=xml");

Console.WriteLine ( doc.ToString() );

/*
<root>
  <id><![CDATA[27]]></id>
  <name><![CDATA[Daft Punk]]></name>
  <link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/artist/27]]></link>
  <picture><![CDATA[http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/27/image]]></picture>
  <nb_album><![CDATA[54]]></nb_album>
  <nb_fan><![CDATA[592180]]></nb_fan>
  <radio><![CDATA[1]]></radio>
  <type><![CDATA[artist]]></type>
*/

Console.WriteLine ( doc.Element("root").Element("name").Value);
// Outputs:
// Daft Punk
```

### Update Alternate Load (Parse)

```
var xml = @"
<root>
  <id><![CDATA[27]]></id>
  <name><![CDATA[Daft Punk]]></name>
  <link><![CDATA[http://www.deezer.com/artist/27]]></link>
  <picture><![CDATA[http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/27/image]]></picture>
  <nb_album><![CDATA[54]]></nb_album>
  <nb_fan><![CDATA[592180]]></nb_fan>
  <radio><![CDATA[1]]></radio>
  <type><![CDATA[artist]]></type>
</root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse( xml );

Console.WriteLine ( doc.Element("root").Element("name").Value);
// Outputs
// Daft Punk
```

Comment: Thx :-) this is usefull but i allready know how to make it this way but i need to do it by webrequest and deserialization. But you showed me how to see things inside so now i just need variable "material" from my code convert to something which can be load by XDocument and display objects inside..

Comment: @Miko The other way to load a XDocument is by the static Parse method, instead of loading it the way I have shown. If that helps. :-)

Comment: Ok im trying to use my old methods and display the result your way but I havent been successful yet :-( . Becouse the values in Xml will be every day different so i cant use just simply linq to website i need to use webrequest deserialize it and than use link to this result.

Comment: I need to do this Document doc = XDocument.Load(material); but in working way.. :-D

Comment: @Miko as long as the data returned from your process is valid xml, then use the parse method as shown in my update above.